DBeaver update Postgres driver version
I'm trying to dump a postgres database that runs version 16.
My driver on DBeaver is version 15, so when I run the dump I get the error:
pg_dump: detail: server version: 16.2; pg_dump version: 15.3
I tried going to Database > Driver Manager > Postgres. Then Edit button, on the pop up I clicked on the Libraries tab and updated everything in there.
Then on Window > Preferences >  Connections > Driver, I checked the option for "Check for new driver versions". Restarted DBeaver and nothing.
I have DBeaver updated to the latest version as well.
I tried going to the folder where the current library is installed, and deleted it. Closed DBeaver and reopened it, it downloads version 15 again.
Searched on here and other foruns, but the closest I got is to have a new one specified, but I need to download it. The directions to download the new client leads to a huge 300+ mb file with a folder structure with lots more files that the current version 15 driver folder, I don't want to bloat my computer with different versions of +300 mb since I work in different projects each running a different version of postgres.
Does anyone have clear directions on how to update or add extra version of a postgres driver?

pg_dump is an application, not a driver. Where did you got this version of the pg_dump application? Did it come with DBeaver?

Where is the Postgres 16 instance located, on your machine or remote?

Hey, i also have a similar issue, Did you find any solution to it? For me the version is: pg_dump: detail: server version: 16.3 (Ubuntu 16.3-1.pgdg20.04+1); pg_dump version: 15.3
